# Is 2GB Ram enough for a snappy 64 bit experience?

Tags: system-requirements

I'm looking at buying a Netbook with 2gb ram and an Intel Atom N450 (64 bit support) and I really want to know if it'll be enough. I'll only be doing stuff such as running emulators from the NES/Famicom - PSP, will I get a speedy experience or should I go for something like MATE?
(I do realize this could be considered a duplicate but other questions don't ask about things such as emulators.)

Comment: MATE is a better interface and it's Gnome 2, you don't need to upgrade something that works ;)

Comment: I'd recommend xubuntu or lubuntu with that little RAM. And a 4G swap partition or swapfile.

Comment: Isn't it too fast to be asking about snappy ? I'm at MATE 16.04 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal experience: I have a 10 year old Dell laptop with Core2Duo, 1.8 GHz, and 2 GB Ram -- and the experience with Kubuntu 14.04 is quite good as long as I don't try to play a games or load complex web pages when I'm off the dock (the machine reduces clock speed to save power when not on the dock).  On battery or the (aftermarket) external charger, it's on the slow side, but still usable for word processing and basic browsing.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect information since KDE is even more heavy on system resources than Ubuntu! Have you tried running an emulator for a 3D-based system? I'd love to play Ps1 games!

Answer (score 0):

2gb is a dangerous line to be walking, but yes it works. As long as you don't try to do too many things at once. Don't know if it is just me but when my laptop runs out of RAM, everything grinds to a halt and I have to reboot.
 HP ProBook 4520s i3 370m @ 2.4Ghz 2GB RAM

Comment: Have you tried to play early 2000's games on it?

Comment: Do you have at least a 4G swap partition or swapfile?

Comment: @Zinux Yes, it can handle NDS, PS1, and most anything older (Save for NGC) @heynnema Nope, I am running off of a USB flash drive and have to minimize how many times the disk is accessed. That means no swap and no `ureadahead`.

Comment: Thank you SO much! Can't wait to play some harvest moon games!

Comment: I think I might go for something like Mate instead though...

Comment: four strikes... 1) running off of a USB stick, 2) no swap, 3) no ureadahead, 4) 2G RAM. No wonder you have a problem that only a reboot can resolve.